# What do the acronyms OBT and OCIP mean on a survey plan?

Tags: markers, land-survey, canada

When looking at survey plans for British Columbia, Canada, there are various acronyms used to describe survey markers. Ones that I do know include:

- BT - bearing tree
- CIP - capped iron post
- PP - "old-style" pipe post
- OIP - original iron post

I am, however, unsure of the acronyms OBT and OCIP. Could they mean "original bearing tree" and "original capped iron post"? If so, what would the qualifier "original" refer to? A previous/different survey plan?

I cannot seem to find answers elsewhere on the 'net.

---

Per request in a comment, I added an image of the OCIP marking
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OBT** “original bearing trees”  (trees are blazed for future reference)

[image]

O**CIP**

[image]

CIP can be denoted as many items but traditionally this was **Capped Iron Posts**

[Disclaimer have used traditional surveying equipment, today it is more Laser and GPS guided]

for more information see
https://www.kleinschmidtsurveying.com/blog/original-bearing-trees

Comment: Thanks. Confirms my suspicion with OBT. However, the OCIP notation is definitely a letter O, not a marker symbol as it is part of a block of text beside the marker symbol (shown as a solid dot). Survey is from 1985. Since posting, I did pull an earlier survey that has the notation CIP at the same location, so I'm guessing that OCIP is "original" CIP.

Comment: @EBlake can you post a sample of your survey in your question?

Comment: As requested, I added a snippet from the map.